# How do I compile dart sass using flutter in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sass

I have been using vscode with dart sass and flutter, however after my most recent update I am having trouble compiling my dart sass.

Here is the code that was working before:

```
import 'dart.io';
import 'package:sass/sass.dart' as sass;

id main(List<String> arguments) {
 var result = sass.compile(arguments[0]);
 new File(arguments[1]).writeAsStringSync(result);
}
```

As mentioned this was working, however I now get a error come up saying:

'compile' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use compileToResult() instead...

I have tried to find a solution but have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It tells you the solution. With the latest version you shsould not use `sass.compile` and use `sass.compileToResult` instead

Comment: Tried that, I get a error return : The argument type "CompileResult' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: That returns a list of loadedUrls from it. So probably you need to something like `result.loladedUrls.first` inside the writeAsStringSync